# Solve: $\frac{1}{2}\log_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(x-1\right)>\log_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(1-\sqrt[3]{2-x}\right)$

Tags: logarithms

Solve: $$\dfrac{1}{2}\log_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(x-1\right)>\log_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(1-\sqrt[3]{2-x}\right)$$

> **My try:** 
>   Conditions identify: $\left\{ \begin{array}{l} x-1>0\\1-\sqrt[3]{2-x}>0\end{array} \right.\Leftrightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{l} x>1\\ \sqrt[3]{2-x}<1 \end{array} \right.\Leftrightarrow x>1$
>
> $\dfrac{1}{2}\log_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(x-1\right)>\log_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(1-\sqrt[3]{2-x}\right)\\\Leftrightarrow \log_{\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{x-1}>\log_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(1-\sqrt[3]{2-x}\right)\\\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{x-1}-1+\sqrt[3]{2-x}<0$

I don't know how to solve this Any equation: $\boxed{\sqrt{x-1}-1+\sqrt[3]{2-x}<0},$ please help me solve that into the result, please guide me, thanks.

Comment: Please help me!

Comment: Nice to see that you are actually showing an attempt now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let me give you a hint.

$$\frac{1}{2}\log_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(x-1\right)>\log_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(1-\sqrt[3]{2-x}\right)$$
so 
$$\log_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(x-1\right)>2\log_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(1-\sqrt[3]{2-x}\right)$$
$$\log_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(x-1\right)>\log_{\frac{1}{2}}[\left(1-\sqrt[3]{2-x}\right)]^2$$
$$\left(x-1\right)<[\left(1-\sqrt[3]{2-x}\right)]^2$$
$$\left(x-1\right)<\left(1-2({2-x})^{\frac{1}{3}}+({2-x})^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)$$
$$0<\left((2-x)-2({2-x})^{\frac{1}{3}}+({2-x})^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)$$
$$0<\left((2-x)^{\frac{3}{3}}-2({2-x})^{\frac{1}{3}}+({2-x})^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)$$

Comment: I thinks your answre is one of the good key for my question, but can you give me the answer for my stuck question that how to solve $\sqrt{x-1}-1+\sqrt[3]{2-x}<0,$ :)

Comment: Actually, $\log_{1/2}$ is decreasing. The inequality should be backwards after that.

Comment: edited! @julien

Comment: it is listed in my answer @AM-GM